# SyCL DPC++: are nVidia GPUs supported in DPC++ under Windows?

Tags: sycl, dpc++

I'm doing some ComputeCpp Vs DPC++ comparisons on Windows. ComputeCpp is fine to me so far, modulo being forced to use the Professional edition to encode multiple spir/PTX targets.

I heard this limitation is not present using DPC++ but, from this post:

[DPC++ under Windows](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-oneAPI-Data-Parallel-C/DPC-for-NVIDIA-CUDA-devices-on-Windows/td-p/1248230)

it seems one year ago nVidia was usable with DPC++ only under Linux, and they were not keen to add any support under Windows to that.

From your experience, is that still the case?

Thanks for your support.

Comment: You can use DPC++ on Windows with the Nvidia GPU support, this is indicated in [these instructions][1].
[1]: https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#build-dpc-toolchain-with-support-for-nvidia-cuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use DPC++ on Windows with the Nvidia GPU support. This is indicated in the [CUDA back-end limitations](https://github.com/intel/llvm/blob/sycl/sycl/doc/GetStartedGuide.md#cuda-back-end-limitations) section of *Getting Started with oneAPI DPC++* instruction.